# truffle migrates the contract with a weird account which is not from my mnemonic

Tags: truffle-migration

I set my infura endpoint and mnemonic to deploy the contract to the Rinkeby testnet. Like this below.

```
const infuraKey = process.env.INFURA_KEY
const test_mnemonic = process.env.TEST_MNEMONIC

networks: {
  rinkeby: {
    provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(test_mnemonic, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}`),
    network_id: 4,
    gas: 6900000,
    gasPrice: 10000000000,
    confirmations: 2,
    timeoutBlocks: 200,
    skipDryRun: true
  }
}
```

My account[0] is `0xeA28Ab53fFF23859c64DB5BAaA64E466713Afae7`, but when I try to deploy with this command `truffle migrate --network rinkeby`, it fails with this error like below.

```
Error: Error: Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds

* Account:  0x9416c8F57eddFeb491F2d728EEb13781662Ac606
* Balance:  0 wei
* Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
* Try:
  + Using an adequately funded account
  + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.

at Object.run (/Users/deleo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:96:1)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I've searched that if my mnemonic includes `0x9416c8F57eddFeb491F2d728EEb13781662Ac606`, but it didn't. I have no idea why truffle keeps migrating with wrong account.

**UPDATE**

I've found that at truffle console (`truffle console --network rinkeby`), I typed `web3.eth.getAccounts()` and it showed that the first account is `0x9416c8F57eddFeb491F2d728EEb13781662Ac606`. Why truffle migrate uses this default account after I set my mnemonic? And where is this default account set from? How could I set my config to use my mnemonic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out! `truffle-hdwallet-provider` module was using it's account[0] from `m/44'/1'/0'/0`. But I was trying to use the account from `m/44'/60'/0'/0` which is by mnemonic creator tool from BIP39. This was the reason.

Comment: could you elaborate? I run into the same problem but I don't understand what are the steps to figure this out

Comment: @Alessandro Solbiati What I did was send some ETH to address showed on `web3.eth.getAccounts()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way for your config:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
require('dotenv').config()

const providerFactory = network =>
  new HDWalletProvider(
    process.env.MNEMONICS || "", // Mnemonics of the deployer
    `https://${network}.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_KEY}`, // Provider URL => web3.HttpProvider
    0,
    20
  );

module.exports = {
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.5.5",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      },
    }
  },
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      provider: providerFactory("rinkeby"),
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 6900000,
      gasPrice: 10000000000 // 10 Gwei
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the result is same.

Comment: Hey @ALATh I've updated my question that I found something else. Could you see it again?

Comment: Perfect that you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

To get all accounts: `truffle develop --network YOUR_NETWORK`

You need to collect the mnemonic showed on prompt and put it on truffle-configs in HDWalletProvider settings:

```
    const ropstenProvider = new HDWalletProvider({
  mnemonic: {phrase: "abc talent waste identify hawk way dolphin crunch maze destroy flock already"},
  providerOrUrl: "wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/..."});
```

After this, you're gonna need to add that "weird account" into your Metamask account. For this, copy the FIRST private key and paste on Metamask -> Import Account -> Private Key.

Now, you can go to a faucet and get some coins with your account already setted.